# Add ajax request to element appended with previous ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of categories and when the client selects one from the list a new list is created below it with the children of that category, now i need to add another level (another list) but i'm not sure how.
This should work but i guess the script can't know if the element is there or not.

So far my JS looks like this:

```
<script>
// when the user clicks on a drop down item from the list it adds a new drop down list
$('#cat_select_1').on('change', function() {

    // fetch second list from the other script
    var fetchUrl = 'http://localhost/includes/ajax/list-of-cats.php?catid=';
    var fetchCatId = $( "#cat_select_1" ).val();

    // if the second list is there
    if ($("#cat_select_2").length){

        // replace it with the new one
        $.get(fetchUrl.concat(fetchCatId)).done(function(data) { $("#cat_select_2").html(data); });
    }
    else {
        // otherwise append this one
        $.get(fetchUrl.concat(fetchCatId)).done(function(data) { $("#jumbocats").append(data); });

    }

});

//list #2 (not working)
$('#cat_select_2').on('change', function() {

    // fetch third list from the other script
    var fetchUrl = 'http://localhost/includes/ajax/list-of-cats.php?catid=';
    var fetchCatId = $( "#cat_select_2" ).val();

    // if the third list is there
    if ($("#cat_select_3").length){

        // replace it with the new one
        $.get(fetchUrl.concat(fetchCatId)).done(function(data) { $("#cat_select_3").html(data); });
    }
    else {
        // otherwise append this one
        $.get(fetchUrl.concat(fetchCatId)).done(function(data) { $("#jumbocats").append(data); });
        }
});

</script>
```

It works for the first list but it doesn't work for the second list.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use direct events with elements that doesn't exist. You need to use delegated events to solve this

```
 $(document).on('change', '#cat_select_2' function() { ... }
```

Where document can be replaced by any parent element that exist at that time.

Check [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation for more details (section "Direct and delegated events")